# Get users' transaction history using Paypal API

Tags: python-2.7, paypal

I'm using Paypal API for the first time and i'm wondering if there is a way I can query the API for a users transaction history. I want it to be in such a way that the user gives my Paypal app permission to access his details then fetches his transaction history. I'm using paypal-rest-sdk for python.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/blob/master/samples/payment/all.py is an example of how do this using the Python sdk.

The all method in the sample wraps "List payment resources" from the API docs https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/